# Shared menu missing from finder sidebar

Tags: finder, high-sierra, back-to-my-mac

Since upgrading to High Sierra the 'Shared' menu (back to my mac, connected servers, bonjour computers) has disappeared from my Finder sidebar. Selecting/de-selecting in preferences makes no difference. Favorites, Devices and Tags all work as expected.

Thanks.

osx 10.13.3 (17D47)

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to High Sierra, I had the same issue, coupled with SMB hanging without connecting to remote servers.

The SMB issue was solved by changing the SMB version to v2 in the /etc/nsmb.conf configuration file and rebooting the Mac as recommended in [this post on SMB share deadlock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309016/smb-share-deadlocks-since-high-sierra). After the reboot with the new /etc/nsmb.conf, shared devices were again correctly listed in the sidebar, so I surmise both issues are linked.

The /etc/nsmb.conf file I use is:

```
$ cat /etc/nsmb.conf
streams=yes
soft=yes
signing_required=no
protocol_vers_map=2
file_ids_off=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested, I resolved this by reinstalling the currently installed osx using the recovery feature, whilst keeping my user files. I guess the in-place upgrade had issues.